# R: Problems using rollapply to sum groups of columns

Tags: r, zoo

I have what should be a simple question, but I'm very new to R so it's stumping me.

I have a series of 25 columns representing trials in a behavioral experiment. I would like to use roll apply to sum the first 5 columns, then 6-10, 11-15, and so on, so that I end up with a new, 5 column data frame containing the output (similar to the 5 column sample below). Really, the point is to be able to rapidly change the "bin size" so that I can make decisions about what "resolution" best suits the data. In the end I wont just be summing, but I think this answer would be plenty to get me rolling.

```
INPUT:
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5
  1      1      1      1      1
  2      2      2      2      2

DESIRED OUTPUT:
Col1
 5
 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming INPUT is a dataframe, maybe something like:

```
sapply(0:((length(LENGTH)-1)/5), function(x) sum(INPUT[, 5*x+1:5]) )
```

I don't think `zoo::rollapply` was conceived of as rolling across columns.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the structure of the arguments. All the apply functions confuse me...I created a simple 3 row data frame with 25 number-filled columns, but I keep getting an error `sapply(0:(length(INPUT)/5), function(x) sum(INPUT[, 5*x+1:5]) )
Error in [.data.frame(INPUT, , 5 * x + 1:5) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: The reason I said "maybe" was that it was untested in the absence of a sample dataset. Which remains the case. If you wnat better answers you should edit your question add the code that creates the sample dataset.